# Current theme for Liferay error page

Tags: liferay, custom-error-pages, liferay-theme

I have a liferay service with many sites. Those sites has the same theme but each has different color scheme. How to set a theme to a /html/portal/status.jsp ( error page) of the current site ? I don't want to create an error page for each site and I don't want all the sites to have the same error page.

Answer (score 1):

One way is override this JSP (using hook / ext) and create `themeCSSPath` using `themeDisplay`, as following:

`themeCSSPath` is the path of the `main.css` of the theme applied on current page.

**CSS path**

```
String themeCSSPath = themeDisplay.getPortalURL() + 
       themeDisplay.getPathThemeCss() + "/main.css";
```

**CSS link**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=themeCSSPath %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to create an error page for each site and I don't want
>   all the sites to have the same error page."

This doesn't make sense.

"/html/portal/status.jsp" is an external JSP page, not part of Portal/Site pages. So, Liferay theme plugin won't work here. You have to design the JSP pages similar to you have on Portal/Site pages.